# How to avoid ORA-00001 in multi target pickList for a table with combined Unique key

Tags: database, hibernate, primefaces, unique-key, picklist

I have a table `UserRoles` with unique_key(fk_User_Id,fk_role_Id) on ORACLE DB

```
ID    |  fk_USER_ID  | fk_ROLE_ID    
1     |   john       |     1
```

and for frontend, I have PrimeFaces pickList that has a source(`this.allRoles`) and target(`roleTarget`).

```
<p:pickList id="rolePickList"
    value="#{userBean.rolesDualModel}"
    var="_role"
    styleClass="width100"
    effect="slide"
    itemValue="#{_role}"
    itemLabel="#{_role.name}"
    showSourceFilter= "true"
    showTargetFilter="true"
    filterMatchMode="contains"
    effectSpeed="fast">
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{userBean.allRoles}" />
     <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Role Available</f:facet>
      <f:facet name="targetCaption">Role Selected</f:facet>
</p:pickList>
```

When I select a `user` from User datatable, `rowSelectListener()` brings the User with his current roles.
All roles take place in source `this.allRoles`(except the User's current roles) and the User's own(current) `roles` take place in the `roleTarget`.

The below method getting all roles from Role Table

```
 private void initializeDualRoles()
    {
        this.allRoles = this.getService().findAll(Role.class);
        this.rolesDualModel = new DualListModel<>(this.allRoles, roleTarget);
    }
```

The below method getting the User's current roles to the `target`

```
 private void adjustDualRoles()
    {
        List<Role> rolesSource = this.getService().findAll(Role.class);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(rolesSource))
        {
            rolesSource.removeAll(this.getModel().getRoles());
        }
        rolesDualModel = new DualListModel<>(rolesSource, this.getModel().getRoles());
    }
```

when I try to set a new Role to a User with Hibernate `SaveOrUpdate()` method;

```
public void save()
    {
            for (Role userRoles : rolesDualModel.getTarget())
            {
                this.getUserRolesBean().getModel().setUserIsn(this.getModel());
                this.getUserRolesBean().getModel().setRoleCode(userRoles);                   
                this.getUserRolesBean().getService().saveOrUpdate(this.getUserRolesBean().getModel());

            }
```

I got

> ORA-0001

Error due to a combined unique key.
It is due to saving the same Model several times in for loop.

If I remove the Combined Unique Key Rule, the rows are duplicated.

Any Idea, How to avoid the error?

Comment: Try check if there is a new Id generated when you try to persist a new row in the UserRoles table

Comment: It is auto generated.

Comment: If you **don't use a database** but a just an array in a bean,  does JSF and PrimeFaces do all they should do? If so, the question is not PF related. If not, the question is not database, hibernate, unique key related. Try creating unittests for the database stuff

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? @Kukeltje this sounds like a problem with hibernate doing more than 1 insert right? OP should carefully debug

Comment: Maybe you have an ID thats duplicated, check in your database maybe your sequence is not being available to continue, just to discard

Comment: @Bugsforbreakfast: Correct. OP should create a service for persistence (not jsf related) and create unittests for this

Comment: and @Kukeltje   Let me explain the issue more clear. Let s say John has role 'admin'. and I wanna set him another role 'super admin'. While I set it, the save method tries to save 'admin' again because of for loop. It should have been update the row via Hibernate, instead creating new row. But, bcz of the combined unique key, Hibernate is not able to update it. and errors.

Comment: Sure, I understand the 'problem', but YOU are responsible for the data(base) model and YOU are responsible for the saving. That is not a picklist or Primefaces thing.

Comment: Okay then, what do you recommend?

Comment: See my previous comments

Comment: @CenfalBahadir dude can you upload the code of your model, the entitys that are causing the problem please, maybe we can see the mistake there in an annotation or something

Comment: @Kukeltje Yesterday a question similar to this one was solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546543/hibernate-inserts-data-into-join-table-twice-causing-ora-00001-unique-constrai#comment105262274_59546543 lets see if maybe its a problem of annotations