# Hibernate inserts data into Join Table twice causing "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I've got two entities mapped with @ManyToMany annotation

**FIRST**

Pielegniarka:

```
 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "pielegniarka")
 public class Pielegniarka {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq2", sequenceName = "pielegniarka_id_pielegniarki", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq2")
    @Column(name = "id_pielegniarki", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int id_pielegniarki;

    @Column(name = "imie")
    private String imie;

    @Column(name = "nazwisko")
    private String nazwisko;

    @Column(name = "placa")
    private int placa;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "pielegniarki_sale",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_pielegniarki"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nr_sali")
    )
    private List<Sala> sale;


    public Pielegniarka() {
    }

    public Pielegniarka(String imie, String nazwisko, int placa, List<Sala> sale) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.sale = sale;
    }

    public void addSala(Sala sala){
        if(sale == null){
            sale = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        sale.add(sala);
    }

    public void removeSala(Sala sala){
        sale.remove(sala);
        sala.getPielegniarki().remove(this);
    }
}
```

**SECOND**

Sala:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Sala {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq3", sequenceName = "sala_nr_sali_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq3")
    @Column(name = "nr_sali", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private int nr_sali;

    @Column(name = "pojemnosc")
    private int pojemnosc;

    @Column(name = "oddzial")
    private String oddzial;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "pielegniarki_sale",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nr_sali"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_pielegniarki")
    )
    private List<Pielegniarka> pielegniarki;


    public Sala() {
    }

    public Sala(int pojemnosc, String oddzial, List<Pielegniarka> pielegniarki) {
        this.pojemnosc = pojemnosc;
        this.oddzial = oddzial;
        this.pielegniarki = pielegniarki;
    }

    public void addPielegniarka(Pielegniarka pielegniarka){
        if(pielegniarki == null){
            pielegniarki = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        pielegniarki.add(pielegniarka);
    }

    public void removePielegniarka(Pielegniarka pielegniarka){
        pielegniarki.remove(pielegniarka);
        pielegniarka.getSale().remove(this);
    }
}
```

I also have a method in my SalaDAO (and similar method in PielegniarkaDAO) which adds Pielegniarka to list in Sala class and then inserts id of that Sala and id of newly added Pielegniarko to Join Table in my Oracle Database (because of @ManyToMany annotation)

```
  @Override
    public void saveSalaWithIdPielegniarki(int idPielegniarki, int nr_sali) {
        Pielegniarka pielegniarka = entityManager.find(Pielegniarka.class, idPielegniarki);
        Sala sala = entityManager.find(Sala.class, nr_sali);

        if (pielegniarka != null && sala != null) {
            for (Pielegniarka salPiel : sala.getPielegniarki()) {
                if (salPiel.getId_pielegniarki() == idPielegniarki) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            pielegniarka.addSala(sala);
            sala.addPielegniarka(pielegniarka);
        }

    }
```

Here is a fragment of SalaController which shows the method doing this. In-service classes I used exactly the same methods as in DAO. It is only a wrapper for DAO classes.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sala")
public class SalaController {

 @PostMapping("/{nr_sali}/pielegniarka/{idPielegniarki}")
    public void saveSalaWithIdPielegniarki(@PathVariable int idPielegniarki,
                                           @PathVariable int nr_sali) {
        salaService.saveSalaWithIdPielegniarki(idPielegniarki,nr_sali);
    }

}
```

When I try to access this endpoint for example /sala/4/pielegniarka/5 which should add Pielegniarka with id 5 to the list of sala with id 4, Hibernate inserts record with id's 4,5 twice into pielegniarki_sale JOIN TABLE in my Database. What can cause this error?

Oracle is throwing "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated" because of that.

Here is the picture of Spring Boot logs that show double insert. And entities relationships image

[Unique constraint violated error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwd2n.png)

[MER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL7h9.png)

Comment: Can you upload an image of your MER for those tables?

Comment: Added image @BugsForBreakfast

Comment: Hmm everything looks fine at simple view, but since you are working with a SEQUENCE, just for discard did you make sure that in your database there is no duplicate id or that the sequence hasn't been "interrupted" for watever reason? like for example having an id at 28 and your sequence is currently at 27, so it tries to use 28 and causes the error happens, check that for discard :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two times defined a ManyToMany relationship with the same realtion table.

You have to make one of the relations the owning and one the inverse side.

The owning side is the side in the realtionship from where the intermidate realtion table is maintainted (insert, update, delete) and the other side, the so called inverse side, is the side where nothing happens in terms of insert, update and delete.

The inserves side is defined when you use the mappedBy attribute that points to the owning side attribute.

For example you could have the owning side like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(
        name = "pielegniarki_sale",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "nr_sali"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_pielegniarki")
)
private List<Pielegniarka> pielegniarki;
```

And then the inverse side like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "pielegniarki")
private List<Pielegniarka> pielegniarki;
```

If you don't do this and let it like your mapping then Hibernate tries to insert two time the same record to the relation table.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me! But to be precise. When I was doing
pielegniarka.add(sala) and then sala.add(pielegniarka) they both were adding record to JOIN TABLE?

Comment: Yes exactly. Please have a look at the docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-entity